# What's the limit of the function $f(x)=\ln x-ax$ $(a>0)$, when $x$ approach $0$ and infinity?

Tags: calculus

I'm a beginner in calculus.

I know when $x \to 0$, $\ln x \to -\infty$ and $-ax \to 0,$ then $\ln x-ax \to -\infty$.

But when $x$ approaches infinity, $\ln x \to \infty$ and $-ax \to -\infty$.

Which one changes faster?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is only one answer for each question you asked. Do you know what happens with $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\ln x\;$ ? Do you know how $\;\ln x\;$ and $\;x\;$ compare when $\;x\to\infty\;$ ? Add some self work.

Comment: Thanks. I know when x approach 0, lnx approach minus infinity and -ax approach 0, then lnx-ax approach minus infinity. But when x approach infinity, lnx approach infinity and -ax approach minus infinity, which one changes faster please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem, otherwise it looks like you are asking others to do your homework for you.

Comment: thanks, i just edited the post adding my thought.

Comment: You have argued that $\lim_{x\to0} f(x) = -\infty$.  So the remaining question is "what is $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$?"

Comment: @chengtang Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^\epsilon}\;,\;\;\text{for any}\;\;\epsilon>0$$ (You may try with L'Hospital, say). That way you'll be able to realize that $\;\ln x\;$ is *eventually* less than $\;x^\epsilon\;$ , for any $\;\epsilon>0\;$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x) = \ln x - a x.$$
$$e^{f(x)} = x e^{-ax} \to 0, \quad \text{ as } x\to \infty.$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Calculate and **think about** $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$.